# What is the "Public" folder used for?

Tags: 13.04, home-directory

In my home folder, there is a folder called `Public`. Why is it put there? Is there any reason a user shouldn't delete it? If it isn't needed perhaps a bug report should be filed, because it was there immediately after I installed the system. It seems to go missing after I delete it and reboot.

I wasn't sure if this was 13.04 specific or not. If it isn't feel free to remove the 13.04 tag and this text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Public` folder is one of the default folders from [xdg-user-dirs](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/). It may be used by programs for files you want to share with others.

If you want to remove that folder you also need to change the file `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`: Replace the line

```
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
```

with

```
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME"
```

Otherwise the folder will be recreated the next time you log in.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It seems, however, that deleting the folder is all you have to do to make it go away... (at least, for now.)